# jQuery $.when in a loop, dosen't wait for each call to be completed before continuing the loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, .when

I use `$.when` to call an ajax function in a loop:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
    $.when(get_total_price("var1","var2")).then(function (v) {
        console.log("i= "+i);
    });
}
```

I expect that in every iteration, it waits for the ajax call to be completed, than the next iteration is executed, so the result of this simple example will be:

```
i= 1
i= 2
i= 3
```

but the result is:

```
i= 5
i= 5
i= 5
```

In this case I can't use the `i` inside the ajax call!

Comment: isn;t Ajax Asynchornous ? If I remember correctly, Ajax is desgined to be Async

Comment: @Satya yes, it's even in the name (**a**synchronous **j**avascript **a**nd **x**ml)

Answer (score 3):

The function callback is done asynchronously and thus called after the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `when` is the deferred model of doing async programming in javascript. The loop terminates before the async functions, i.e. when callbacks, are called. Here is a hack to make it work by using [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
    (function() {
        $.when(get_total_price("var1","var2")).then(function (v) {
            console.log("i= "+i);
        })
    )(i);
}
```